# How to create plots at runtime (OxyPlot)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, oxyplot

I want to have a button which, when clicked, creates a new instance of a PlotView and adds it to a StackPanel. How can I do this?

I tried to come up with something but it doesn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var plotView = new PlotView();
            plotView.Height = 300;
            plotView.Width = 600;
            plotView.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            var oxyPlotModel = new OxyPlotModel();
            var plotModel = new PlotModel();
            plotView.DataContext = oxyPlotModel;
            oxyPlotModel.PlotModel = plotModel;
            SetUpAxes(ref plotModel);
            plotModel.Axes[1].IsZoomEnabled = true;

            stackPanel1.Children.Add(plotView);
        }

        private void SetUpAxes(ref PlotModel plotModel)
        {
            plotModel.Axes.Clear();
            foreach (var axis in plotModel.Axes)
                axis.Reset();
            var yAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis();
            var xAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis();
            yAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
            yAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = -50;
            yAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = 450;
            yAxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
            xAxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
            xAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/14 " + "00:00:00").Ticks));
            xAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/14 " + "00:00:00").AddDays(1).Ticks));
            yAxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
            yAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
            yAxis.Font = "Open Sans";
            xAxis.Font = "Open Sans";
            plotModel.Axes.Add(yAxis);
            plotModel.Axes.Add(xAxis);
        }
    }
```

Here is my viewmodel:

```
public class OxyPlotModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private OxyPlot.PlotModel plotModel;
        public OxyPlot.PlotModel PlotModel
        {
            get
            {
                return plotModel;
            }
            set
            {
                plotModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlotModel");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option is to make the PlotViews invisible in the xaml itself and then reveal them one by one after a press of the button, but I feel like this method is better.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good job for a ListBox.  In essence, just add your new chart to an iobservablecollection of charts.

xaml

```
<button command="{binding AddChart}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChartDataSets}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <views:OxyPlotChart MinWidth="600" MinHeight="300" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

OxyPLotChart.xaml

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding}" />
```

in OxyPlotModel (*assuming your code is correct)

```
public IObservableCollection<PlotView> ChartDataSets;

public DelegateCommand AddChart { get; private set;}

public OxyPlotModel()
{
    ChartDataSets = new ObservableCollection<PlotView>();
    AddChart = new DelegateCommand(AddOxyChart);
}

private void AddOxyChart()
{
     var plotView = new PlotView();
     plotView.Height = 300;
     plotView.Width = 600;
     plotView.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
     var oxyPlotModel = new OxyPlotModel();
     var plotModel = new PlotModel();
     plotView.DataContext = oxyPlotModel;
     oxyPlotModel.PlotModel = plotModel;
     SetUpAxes(ref plotModel);
     plotModel.Axes[1].IsZoomEnabled = true;

     ChartDataSets.Add(plotView);
}

private void SetUpAxes(ref PlotModel plotModel)
{
    plotModel.Axes.Clear();
    foreach (var axis in plotModel.Axes)
        axis.Reset();
    var yAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis();
    var xAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis();
    yAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
    yAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = -50;
    yAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = 450;
    yAxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
    xAxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
    xAxis.AbsoluteMinimum = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime (Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/14 " + "00:00:00").Ticks));
     xAxis.AbsoluteMaximum = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/14 " + "00:00:00").AddDays(1).Ticks));
    yAxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
    yAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
    yAxis.Font = "Open Sans";
    xAxis.Font = "Open Sans";
    plotModel.Axes.Add(yAxis);
    plotModel.Axes.Add(xAxis);
}
```

Comment: Note : Here is why you should use an observablecollection over a list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding